# ARCore TransformableNode sets localPosition to [x=0.0, y=0.0, z=0.0] after dragging

Tags: java, android, arcore, sceneform

I am creating a multiplayer experience for ARCore. So i want to share the **`LocalPosition`** of an **`TransformableNode`** that is set to a plane.

So when i am setting my `TransformableNode` to a `ParentNode` and then set the `LocalPosition`, everything is alright and i get with `getLocalPosition()` the correct localPosition.

If i now drag the node to another point on the plane it seems that the `TransformableNode` lost its `ParentNode`. Because after dragging the `node` i get with `getLocalPosition() ->  [x=0.0, y=0.0, z=0.0]` and not the Postion in relation to the parent i set previously.

```
myAnchorNode.addChild(myTransformableNode);
myTransformableNode.setLocalPosition(position);
//dragging it at runtime
Vector3 x = myTransformableNode.getLocalPosition(position);
// x = [x=0.0, y=0.0, z=0.0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use this method instead, to get relative position.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html

ARCore manipulates a lot of objects in its own hierarchy, and is probably causing a conflict.

Comment: That helps me a lot! But i am using Android Studio to work with ARCore. And obviously this method isn't there. But i found similar methods that convert my position and should do the trick.